# Type mismatch, but code working

Tags: type-mismatch

I know this kind of topic is quite common, but I can't find an answer for my problem. Could anyone help me on why type mismatch error appears (the code works however):

```
Sub CreateEMail2()
    Dim Email As String, Subj As String
    Dim Msg As String, URL As String
    Dim iCounter As Integer, x As Double

    For iCounter = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(13))
        Email = Cells(iCounter, 13)

        Subj = "Atgādinājums par parādu"

        Msg = ""
        Msg = Msg & "Klients: " & Cells(iCounter, 1) & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "Vēlamies atgādināt, ka uz epasta izsūtīšanas brīdi Jūsu kavētā parāda kopsumma sastāda EUR "

        Msg = Msg & Cells(iCounter, 6).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg

        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you using any particular programming language? (In any case, I am voting to close, because you don't describe the exact problem you observe.)

Comment: I am trying to write this code in VBA in excel. the code works though, I can't just get rid of the error message. If any idea, i'd be grateful. as to your comment - any additional info needed? it's my first time asking this kind of questions, thus please excuse if not done properly

Comment: You should isolate your error message - tell us when (and where) it appears, and its exact text.

Comment: The message states as this: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. it appears before it actually creates emails. the message does not appear if I change the code for a fixed range of iCounter (e.g. For iCounter = 5 To 9) (I hope you could understand what I wrote - english is far from my natice language)

Comment: Isolate it to locate it. If you can't debug (you _should_ debug, definitely), just put a MsgBox before each line and see which is the last one to appear before the type mismatch. Divide and conquer.

Comment: thanks :) it was a stupid mistake! fixed it :)